# Websphere creating dump only on server start up

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

Whenever I start the websphere from my IBM Rational Application developer, it is creating dump inside

```
profiles\AppSrv1
```

and

```
C:\Server\profiles\AppSrv1\bin\
```

and then I have to stop the process under task manager, delete dump files.

Please make a note that I've not logged into the application, only the server start up is creating heap dump

Why is it happening? Any ideas will be helpful for me.

Comment: Probably your heap sizes are too low, and you are hitting out of memory error, which triggers the dump. Check SystemOut.log and native_stderr.logs maybe you will find additional info what causes that.

Comment: did you manage to fix this one? I am facing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the automated heap dump is enabled. Check that the checkbox value of `Enable automatic heap dump collection` under `Servers -> Performance -> Runtime` in the console.

Comment: There is no performance option, when I right click on Servers

Comment: Uhm, you should find Application servers under servers, then Performance and Diagnostic.

Comment: Are you talking in IBM RAD? I dont see application servers option

Comment: Oh I got it.. You are talking about Admin console